# Query to check if the seats are already occupied

Tags: sql, subquery, not-exists

I have this assignment where i need to build a reservation system for a theater.
I am trying to build a query that shows me all seats that are not occupied. At this moment i have made this:

```
select rownumber, seatnumber
from seats
where not exists 
(
      select seatnumber
      from occupation
      where shownumber = 1 and performancenumber = 1
)
order by rownumber, seatnumber
```

Could someone explain me why it doesnt show any results? when i run only the subquery it shows me all the seats that are occupied.

I have tried to look in other forums, but i did not find any answers.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select rownumber, seatnumber
from seats
where not exists (select seatnumber
                  from occupation
                  where shownumber = 1 and performancenumber = 1
                 )
order by rownumber, seatnumber;
```

This returns no rows, because the subquery always returns some row -- if at least one seat is occupied.

You want a correlated subquery:

```
select rownumber, seatnumber
from seats s
where not exists (select o.seatnumber
                  from occupation o
                  where shownumber = 1 and performancenumber = 1 and
                        o.seatnumber = s.seatnumber and o.rownumber = s.seatnumber
                 )
order by rownumber, seatnumber;
```

Comment: This seems to work but the problem is that it will also exclude seats (with the same seatnumber) from rows that are not occupied.

Comment: @user3188517 . . . I didn't realize that both numbers are required to identify a seat.  I thought `seatnumber` was enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
select rownumber, seatnumber
from seats
where seatnumber not in
(
  select seatnumber
  from occupation
  where shownumber = 1 and performancenumber = 1
)
order by rownumber, seatnumber
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the problem is that every row has the same seatnumbers. So if i run this query i will also filter other seats than the that is occupied. so actualy i need to filter it on 2 colums. seatnumber and rownumber

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is correct when you join by seat number and row number... another way you could do this is

```
select s.rownumber, s.seatnumber
from seats s
left outer join occupation o
on (o.seatnumber = s.seatnumber
and o.rownumber = s.rownumber)
where (s.shownumber = 1 and s.performancenumber = 1 and s.rownumber is null)
order by rownumber, seatnumber;
```

The reason I mention this is because you may find performance differences between left outer join and where not exists. In my experience WHERE NOT EXISTS can be a bit slow on updates and deletes... but then again I've heard others say the exact opposite. Regardless, Gordon is right. And there is another way to go about it, if you want to give that a shot too.